# It doesn't return the index of everysingle letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
def capital_indexes(string):
    cap=[]
    for i in string:
            if i.isupper()==True:
                    cap.append(string.find(i))
    return cap
print(capital_indexes("TEsT"))
```

I want it to return the index of every single letter that is a capital letter.

Comment: Your first step should be to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), which clearly states that it finds only the _first occurrence_ of your search string. Why do you need to use `find` in the first place? You already know the index you're iterating over, just use `enumerate`

Comment: What is it doing instead? It's important to include that as part of a complete description of your issue.

That said, I suspect that your implementation is failing because of repeated letters - in the string "AA" it will "find" the first index twice.

Comment: Dont loop and search using `find`. Loop over the `len()` range and use `string[index]` and then append `index`

Answer (score 2):

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    return [e for e,i in enumerate(s) if i.isupper()]

print(capital_indexes("TEsT"))  #[0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.find` returns the index of the first value found. You have 2 `T` s, but it will return `0` for each. The `enumerate` function gives you the index of the value iterated, use that instead.

```
def capital_indexes(string):
    cap=[]
    for i,c in enumerate(string):
            if c.isupper()==True:
                    cap.append(i)
    return cap
print(capital_indexes("TEsT"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `enumerate()` so that you are given the correct index without having to find it:

```py
def capital_indexes(string):
    cap = []
    for idx,c in enumerate(string):
        if c.isupper():
            cap.append(idx)
    return cap
print(capital_indexes("TEsT"))
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, without enumerate:

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    return [i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i].isupper()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `list`, `filter` and `lambda`:

```
def capital_indexes(s): 
    return list(filter(lambda i: s[i].isupper(), range(len(s))))

print(capital_indexes("TEsT"))

# [0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` finds the first occurrence of the character in the String. Therefore, it returns `[0, 1, 0]`. Also there is no need for `i.isupper()==True` as `i.isupper()` in itself a boolean value.

```
def capital_indexes(string):
    cap=[]
    for num, char in enumerate(string):
            if char.isupper():
                    cap.append(num)
    return cap

print(capital_indexes("TEsT"))  #[0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The i iterator used in the for loop gives you the character, not the index.

String.find(i) will return the position of the character in the string.

You can simply append the character into the cap array instead of using string.find(i).

cap.append(i)

Comment: OP wants the index of the letters, not the letters themselves.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).